# Use dynamic variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two "div" tags:
I use "each function" to declare variables for each "div"
I can only access the second variable inside the "each function". and i can't access neither of the variables outside the function.

Here is the code:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>

var j = 0;
$("div").each(function () {
    j++;
    eval("var k" + j + "=0;");
}
```

How can i access both, inside or outside the function?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Never use `eval` it's `evil` - Douglas Crockford

Comment: Try the [data api](http://api.jquery.com/data)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It's likely there's a much better approach.

Comment: where and you are trying to access the values again

Comment: You really don't need to have `k0`, `k1`, `k2`, etc. variables. See how arrays work.

Comment: @ArunPJohny in another function

Comment: j = 0; $("div").click(function () { j++; alert(eval("k" + j + "=0;")); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var j = 0;
  $("div").each(function()
  {
    j++;
    window['k' + j] = 0;
  });
  console.log(k1);
  console.log(k2);
</script>
```

But this is not the way to go !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what's going on in your code,
You are trying to define `j` variables, and set their value to zero.
Where `j` being the number of `<div>`s

If so, this is a better approach:

```
j=$("div").length;
var k =new Array(j);
```

And you can access them by:

```
k[0]
```

instead of

```
k0
```

See: [Javascript arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)